# How to create a Windows 8 startup disk from ubuntu?

Tags: 11.04, windows, dual-boot, usb-drive, windows-8

First of all, I'm not a windows fan. I just want to try windows 8. But I can't boot the usb after extracting the developer release with Unetbootin. The blogs mention a Windows 7 USB DVD tool which doesn't run with wine.

Comment: It'll be a little slower installing, but I'm assuming you could always burn it to a DVD. The other thing you could try is VirtualBox, though I don't know how well it will work in there.

Comment: check this video out on how to install windows 8 in ubuntu via virtual box. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dB9jnkly4MU

Comment: I don't wanna try it in virtual box.

Comment: ok I'm sorry I just wanted to show you that it works well in a virtual box. That way if you can't install it in your computer you can try it in a virtual box. Just trying to help you so can have a glimpse of windows 8 firsthand.

Comment: I don't think Windows supports this method of installation

Comment: @UriHerrera I guess so. Though I doubt windows 7 having a similar problem.

Comment: Unetbootin will not Work with Windows because it uses Isolinux i think to boot the distro's and of course the bootable files are not the same for Windows and for a linux distro, same goes for the startup disk creator, you're better off just trying it in virtualbox or using using a spare hard drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crazy answer, Install VirtualBox, Install Win8 to VBox, Boot new VBox image, use the Windows7 USB DVD tool, and install to machine.

Comment: I agree that he should seriously consider whether he really wants a full install on bare hardware. Thought people were confused by GNOME Shell and Unity? Even I think Metro UI would confuse me extremely, and being in development status Windows 8 isn't even anything close to stable right now.

Comment: @vkcaspervk pretty good! btw I used the Windows7 USB DVD tool from my friend's windows 7 system =) And yes Windows 8 is a horror, but I wanted to show my friends how it looks.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 As I said above, I wanted to show off a triple boot ( win8, natty and oneiric )

Answer (score 3):

Simple, install and use WinUSB:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

It works with Windows 7/8.

Via [Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/tool-to-create-windows-usb-install.html)